# nginx + uWSGI + Django crashes with benchmarking tool wrk

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, wrk

I have configured nginx, uWSGI server for my Django application. Everything seems fine, bet when I do some requests using wrk, nginx server instantly starts to respond 502 Bad Gateway (I think uWSGI crashes). When I stop wrk, everything starts to work properly. Is there some limit, how many requests can be made on certain amount of time or something else? This is a very bad issue, since the system will crash if lots of users will use it.

My uWSGI configuration:

```
[uwsgi]

base         = /home/user/
project      = app
home         = %(base)/env
module       = %(project).wsgi:application

master       = true
processes    = 5

socket       = /var/sockets/app.sock
chmod-socket = 664
uid          = www-data
gid          = www-data

harakiri     = 600
vacuum       = true

die-on-term  = true
```

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset     utf-8;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/user/app/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/user/app/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass         unix:/var/sockets/app.sock;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
        include            /home/user/app/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Someone with a similar problem](http://%20down%20vote%20accepted%20%09%20%20This%20should%20fix%20it...%20%20You%20have:%20fastcgi_buffers%204%20256k;%20%20Change%20it%20to:%20fastcgi_buffers%20256%2016k;%20//%204096k%20total%20%20Also%20set%20fastcgi_max_temp_file_size%200,%20that%20will%20disable%20buffering%20to%20disk%20if%20replies%20start%20to%20exceeed%20your%20fastcgi%20buffers.) was given [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707319/1587329):

> This should fix it...
>
> You have: `fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;`
>
> Change it to: `fastcgi_buffers 256 16k; // 4096k total`
>
> Also set `fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0`, that will disable buffering
>   to disk if replies start to exceeed your fastcgi buffers.

Have you tried that?